# translate from Mathematica to maxima

Tags: wolfram-mathematica, maxima

I am tryingt o convert a code from Mathematica to Maxima. The code is around 300 lines, I did not write it and the person who did was not good with comments. I was wondering if anyone know of a program that does converting like this?

I tried one from source forge called mixima but I could not get it to run.

Best,
Ben

Answer (score 2):

Converting from Mathematica syntax to Maxima is pretty straightforward. Somewhere out on the Interwebs there is a "Rosetta Stone" of programming languages that might help. (Found this [1] which seems helpful, although I seem to recall something more extensive. Can't find anything else at the moment.)

However, the difficult part is that there might be functions which work differently in one system or the other. In particular, I think Mathematica's function for solving equations is more powerful than Maxima's. So whether or not you can translate the code depends on more than just converting the syntax. My advice is to post the code to the Maxima mailing list (maxima@math.utexas.edu) and ask whether it can be translated.

[1] http://www.axiom-developer.org/axiom-website/rosetta.html

Comment: This "rosetta stone" is called rosetta code, by the way